# Can I use my android phone as finger print, webcam, and mic for my windows 10PC?

Tags: fingerprint

I suppose I can buy a mic, a webcam, and a finger print censor for my windows 10.

But I have all those in android phone already.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As for the camera and mic part**,

If you simply search the web for phrases like *"use Android camera/mic on PC"*, you will come across many apps; some of them actually do the job.

I have used an app called [DroidCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam) in the past which had worked for me in Windows 7 after a litte bit of struggling. (I have never tried it in Windows 10, though; but I guess it should work)

**As for the fingerprint reader part**,

There is not a solution which can be assured to work flawlessly. But there are some things which might be helpful :-

- [**Dynamic Lock**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028111/windows-lock-your-windows-10-pc-automatically-when-you-step-away-from) by Microsoft — If you are simply looking for a solution to unlock your PC using your phone, then this might be the solution for you. Although it doesn't specifically use a fingerprint unlock, it allows you to keep your PC unlocked when your phone is close enough and reachable via Bluetooth.
- **Third-party solution** — There is an app called [Remote Fingerprint Unlock](https://www.xda-developers.com/unlock-windows-pc-fingerprint-scanner-android) which is slightly complicated to set up but will do the job for you.
- [**Samsung Flow**](https://www.xda-developers.com/new-samsung-flow-update-lets-you-unlock-any-windows-device-via-fingerprint-and-more) — If you happen to have a Samsung Android phone, then this solution from Samsung should work for you. 
  This app has also been [ported to non-Samsung devices](https://www.xda-developers.com/samsung-flow-ported-non-samsung-devices) by some developer(s) but the Fingerprint unlock functionality **does not** work on non-Samsung devices yet.

(Mentioning the below content just for the sake of completeness; doesn't answer this question)

- **Google Smart Lock for Chromebooks** — This is a solution provided by Google to unlock your PC with a fingerprint scanner on your phone. However this only works on Chrome OS (v71+) and not on any other OS.

Comment: chrome os? PC running on chrome os? Something besides microsoft?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: As for the Chrome OS part, I have specifically mentioned that this solution does not apply to your question. I have mentioned it just for the sake of completeness.
With a PC running on Chrome OS, I was referring to both – Chromebook and Chromebase.